# Add hyperlinks within videos

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

**Is it possible to add clickable menus to videos?**  Like with DVD's?

Plus, **is it possible to have areas of a video image clickable?**  For example a scene where each actor in a movie could be clicked?  I am thinking of something like HTML image maps, but with video?

I use Linux and ffmpeg for all of my transcoding.

Any pointers, much appreciated. Thanks, as always.

Talk to you all soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that at transcoding time.
If we're talking about videos you intend to play in a HTML5 player, I'd suggest https://h5p.org/

Note however, that FFmpeg does include a `drawbox` filter, which you can use for displaying links or any other string for that matter: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox

Cheers,

Comment: I was more thinking of if I could have a text file with timestamps set, where I can overlay text/images/links to videos.  It would take forever if I had to use a GUI.  I suppose HTML5 is the way to go.